# wait for all streams to finish - stream a directory of files

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I'm using [client.upload](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud/blob/master/docs/providers/rackspace/storage.md#clientuploadoptions) in [pkgcloud](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud) to upload a directory of files. How can I execute a callback after all the streams have finished? Is there a built-in way to register each stream's "finish" event and execute a callback after they have all fired?

```
var filesToUpload = fs.readdirSync("./local_path"); // will make this async

for(let file of filesToUpload) {
    var writeStream = client.upload({
        container: "mycontainer",
        remote: file
    });
    // seems like I should register finish events with something
    writeStream.on("finish", registerThisWithSomething);
    fs.createReadStream("./local_path/" + file).pipe(writeStream);
}
```

Comment: You can use async.js for this kind of problem. You can use  method provided by async.js as `async.waterfall()`.The result of one function will be passed to another as a callback arguments.You should check out the documentation of it .

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One way to do it, is to generate a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) task for each upload, then utilizing [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Assuming you are using ES6, then the code would look something like this:

```js
    const uploadTasks = filesToUpload.map((file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var writeStream = client.upload({
            container: "mycontainer",
            remote: file,
        });
        // seems like i should register finish events with something
        writeStream.on("finish", resolve);
        fs.createReadStream("./local_path/" + file).pipe(writeStream);
    }));

    Promise.all(uploadTasks)
      .then(() => { console.log('All uploads completed.'); });
```

Alternatively, if you have access to [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) - you can utilize this. For example:

```js
    const uploadFile = (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const writeStream = client.upload({
        container: "mycontainer",
        remote: file,
      });
      writeStream.on("finish", resolve);
      fs.createReadStream("./local_path/" + file).pipe(writeStream);
    });
    
    const uploadFiles = async (files) => {
      for(let file of files) {
        await uploadFile(file);
      }
    }

    await uploadFiles(filesToUpload);
    console.log('All uploads completed.');
```

Comment: For those who are interested, I had a slightly different problem while handling streams in hummus.js and this answer helped me solve my problem! Thanks @JAM

my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731191/how-to-modify-a-stream-from-request-to-a-new-response-stream-in-hummusjs

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis missing after the end of the promise (in both examples, which is kind of interesting), but SO won't let me add it because edits must comprise at least 6 characters.

Comment: Good catch @sgrubsmyon - I've added the missing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NodeDir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dir#usage)，which has methods like `readFilesStream` / `promiseFiles` etc.